# Pagination don't work in custom page template

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I created a custom page template like category.php but I can't get the pagination working.
I just filter post from one category.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: News */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 content">

<div class="box">
    <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div class="box-int">
      <article>

        <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l


        $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php 
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
          the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        ?>

        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <br><br>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

        <nav id="nav-posts">
          <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Old'); ?></div>
          <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newx &raquo;'); ?></div>
        </nav>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <nav id="nav-posts">
          <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Old'); ?></div>
        </nav>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

      </article>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What's wrong here? I click in Page 2, but the post are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit of a mess here with some syntax errors as well.`showposts` died with the dinosaurs, it is long time depreciated. You should use `posts_per_page`. `'showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged` is also a mess. You query shouls simplify look like this

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
```

When querying the loop with WP_Query, you need to assign `$max_pages` parameter to the [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link).

So you would need to change `<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Old'); ?>` to `<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Old', $the_query->max_num_pages ); ?>`

Also go and read [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops) on this subject. If I missed something, this question will most certainly help you out a lot.

Comment: Don't worked. The link send to page/2/ but the post are always the same.

Comment: @OsnyNetto check update. The link I provided will help you out big time.

Comment: I tried even the code above "Putting it all together" and can't work.

Comment: @OsnyNetto You're query is a total mess, please check my update